# Cannot get the right way to make a fuzzy logic problem to work with the mom defuzzy method

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic

I'm new to fuzzy logic, I'm trying to get the power of a heater with the mom defuzzy method when the temperature is 27 degree

I'm having an error because the first and second element of the `defuzz` method should be an array of the same size, but I'm not sure how to write the problem/code

```
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl

# Definir el universo de discurso para temperatura y potencia
temperatura = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 41, 1), 'temperatura')
potencia = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 101, 1), 'potencia')

# Definir las funciones de membresía para temperatura
temperatura['baja'] = fuzz.trimf(temperatura.universe, [0, 10, 15])
temperatura['media'] = fuzz.trapmf(temperatura.universe, [10, 15, 25, 30])
temperatura['alta'] = fuzz.trimf(temperatura.universe, [25, 30, 40])

# Definir las funciones de membresía para potencia
potencia['baja'] = fuzz.trimf(potencia.universe, [0, 20, 30])
potencia['media'] = fuzz.trapmf(potencia.universe, [20, 30, 60, 70])
potencia['alta'] = fuzz.trimf(potencia.universe, [60, 70, 100])

# Visualización de las funciones de membresía
temperatura.view()
potencia.view()

# Definir las reglas difusas
regla1 = ctrl.Rule(temperatura['baja'], potencia['alta'])
regla2 = ctrl.Rule(temperatura['media'], potencia['media'])
regla3 = ctrl.Rule(temperatura['alta'], potencia['baja'])

# Crear el sistema de control difuso
sistema_control = ctrl.ControlSystem([regla1, regla2, regla3])

# Crear el simulador del sistema de control difuso
simulador = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(sistema_control)

# Establecer la temperatura de entrada
simulador.input['temperatura'] = 27  # Temperatura de ejemplo

# Realizar la inferencia
simulador.compute()

# Obtener el valor de potencia de salida
potencia_mom = fuzz.defuzz(potencia.universe, simulador.output['potencia'], 'mom')
```